# Temporary Function for one-time script in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, arrays, t-sql

In SQL Server 2008, I'm creating a script to convert a column to another type of column, and then replace the data with data from another table (We're using a new ID).
I can do:

```
ALTER TABLE @tablename
ALTER COLUMN AccountID VARCHAR(30);

UPDATE @tablename
SET AccountID = SELECT AccountNumber
                  FROM OtherTable
                 WHERE AccountID = AccountID;
```

The only problem is that I have to run these same two commands for some 20-odd tables. Is there anyway to loop through these two, or write them as a temporary function/method/etc? I don't want to keep it, because we'll only need to do this once. Particularly, I'm having trouble creating a list of tables to loop through. I really want to find a better way than creating a function, running it on the tables, and then dropping it.

Comment: I would think that since this is a one time thing, copy and paste will take the least amount of time.

Comment: you could use a cursor to iterate through names and execute dynamic sql for each table.

Comment: I thought cursors could only be on tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple select to sys.objects to get the script you need to execute.
You will have to turn on Result-To-Text, for example from [SSMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio) by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, and then executing:

```
SELECT '
    ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME([name]) + '
    ALTER COLUMN AccountID VARCHAR(30);

    UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME([name]) + '
    SET AccountID = SELECT AccountNumber
                      FROM OtherTable
                     WHERE AccountID = AccountID;'
FROM sys.objects
WHERE [type] = 'u'
AND [name] in ('OneTable', 'AnotherTable', 'AndSoOn')
```

After that, you only have to copy the result text and execute it.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help. This is perfect, I was thinking in procedural terms, not database terms. Just one thing, wouldn't it be better coming from sys.tables? Faster, at least?